# Change the text color of the "new branch" popup in VS2019

Tags: colors, fonts, popup

So I'm creating a new branch in VS2019 and looking at this:
[New branch popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7wU8.png)
The checkout section appears to be messed up. I cannot actually see if the checkbox is selected.

I'm using the MonokaiVS theme for VS2019. This selection seems to affect the way the popup for new branch appears as well. Is there a way ( or an option I'm not seeing in fonts and colors ) to customize it so that it can be more readable?